# How to connect a model with foreign key in a function which uploads a csv file in django?

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-orm

I have a django web app where I want users to upload their data in the form of csv. I have created a function and a page where the user uploads csv, and I have appended the user to the model, but I want that user to be the foreign key for each of the files. From what I see, the data is being entered in the database just fine but I do not think it is properly connected with a foreign key because on analyzing the database it says there are no foreign keys connected, and just the value is being entered with no relation what so ever.

Here is my function:

```
def upload_batch(request):
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/upload.html'
    prompt = {'order':'Order of csv should be first_name, last_name, email, ip_address, message'}
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,template_name,prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)


    uploaded_by = request.user


    for column in csv.reader(io_string,delimiter=',',quotechar='|'):
        _, created = ItemBatch.objects.update_or_create(
            name = column[0],
            pid = column[1],
            quantity = column[2],
            length = column[3],
            width = column[4],
            height = column[5],
            volume = column[6],
            weight = column[7],
            uploaded_by = uploaded_by
        )


    context = {}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Here is my model:

```
# item upload
class ItemBatch(models.Model):

    # uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')

    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

UPDATE: Here is a screenshot of the model in my database.As you can see, the `uploaded_by` is not being shown as a foreign key, just like it is being shown in this other working model.

My model in database:
[image: 1]

Foreign key tab is empty.
[image: 1]

My other working model with FK.
[image: 3]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. What makes you think the FK isn't being set? Also are you sure the user is logged in? Have you tried using the `@login_required` decorator?

Comment: You would get a database error if you were saving a `ItemBatch` without `uploaded_by` set correctly, since it's required and cannot be null. So if you see items being saved in the database, then they must have a correct foreign key assigned.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated my question as to why I think a proper FK is not being created.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in those screenshots. In the first one, `uploaded_by_id` is clearly being populated. Why do you think that is incorrect? I don't know what that "Foreign key" tab is supposed to show, but if there is anything wrong there that is to do with your original table setup, not the upload_batch code.

Answer (score 0):

The code and the model looks fine.
Did you make some changes to the model in the past (and ran `makemigrations`, `migrate`)? 
According to your screenshots there is no foreign key constraint on that table, which is strange since it seems to get populated correctly. 
Did you refresh/synchronize the schema in the tool?

Comment: I certainly did. Please suggest some solid method to debug this, and your 'answer' is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, this is more of a comment than an answer, but as a new user I just didn't have the privileges to post comments. I will check if there's a way to debug this though.

Comment: Oh right, I just saw that. Weird SO rules. Though I was able to circumvent this problem in a different way.